# Does this operator exist ? "@>" in SQL

Tags: sql

I just saw an ad on YouTube for some dataviz software, with the following code :

```
SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar @> '{"fizz", "buzz", "fizzbuzz"}'
```

which contains this `@>` operator. It seems to be similar to the `LIKE` operator, but I've never seen it used anywhere. Does it exist (is it specific to some SQL DBMS ?), and if so what does it do ?

Here is a screenshot of the ad (I covered the name of the brand) :

[image: @> operator]

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36985926/330315

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operator exists in Postgres.  It is the "contains" operator to see if one array contains another.

The documentation is [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is the "contains" operator.

Check this for more: 
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html

They are defined for other types as well for eg. Range @> int4range(0,3).