# In clause in postgres

Tags: postgresql

Need Output from table with in clause in PostgreSQL

I tried to make loop or ids passed from my code. I did same to update the rows dynamically, but for select I m not getting values from DB

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dashboard.rspgetpendingdispatchbyaccountgroupidandbranchid(
IN accountgroupIdCol    numeric(8,0),
IN branchidcol      character varying 
)
RETURNS void
AS
$$
DECLARE 
    ArrayText text[];
    i int;
BEGIN
     select string_to_array(branchidcol, ',') into ArrayText; 
     i := 1;
     loop  
     if i > array_upper(ArrayText, 1) then
     exit;
     else
        SELECT 
        pd.branchid,pd.totallr,pd.totalarticle,pd.totalweight,
        pd.totalamount
        FROM dashboard.pendingdispatch AS pd
        WHERE
        pd.accountgroupid = accountgroupIdCol AND pd.branchid IN(ArrayText[i]::numeric);    
        i := i + 1;
    end if;
    END LOOP;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' VOLATILE;
```

Comment: Do you find something like this?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54155256

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for a loop (or PL/pgSQL actually)

You can use the array directly in the query, e.g.:

```
where pd.branchid = any (string_to_array(branchidcol, ','));
```

But your function does not return anything, so obviously you won't get a result.

If you want to return the result of that SELECT query, you need to define the function as `returns table (...)` and then use `return query` - or even better make it a SQL function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dashboard.rspgetpendingdispatchbyaccountgroupidandbranchid(
  IN accountgroupIdCol    numeric(8,0),
  IN branchidcol      character varying )
RETURNS table(branchid integer, totallr integer, totalarticle integer, totalweight numeric, totalamount integer)
AS
$$
  SELECT pd.branchid,pd.totallr,pd.totalarticle,pd.totalweight, pd.totalamount
  FROM dashboard.pendingdispatch AS pd
  WHERE pd.accountgroupid = accountgroupIdCol
    AND pd.branchid = any (string_to_array(branchidcol, ',')::numeric[]);
$$ 
LANGUAGE sql 
VOLATILE;
```

Note that I guessed the data types for the columns of the query based on their names. You have to adjust the line with `returns table (...)` to match the data types of the select columns.

Comment: Hi thank u for modification but with this also i m getting this error

Comment: ERROR:  operator does not exist: numeric = text
LINE 10:   WHERE pd.branchid = any (string_to_array(branchidcol, ',')...
                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.

Comment: can u help in this

Comment: My simple intension is to get the values from tables using multiples ids as we do in sql In clause

Comment: The function will do that. Btw:it would be more efficient to use `integer` or `bigint` for `ID` columns, rather than `numeric`

Comment: Thank u Very much ! It Worked For Me !