# Should I extract the "time" part of "timestamp" into "json" data type?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, database-design, database-schema

I am designing a database([postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/index.html)) that can store a user's meals across the day, and there'll be weekly, monthly, or yearly analysis based these everyday information in the future. My original design was to have a `meals` table that looks like:

**`meals`** (table name)

- id (primary key)
- user_id (foreign key)
- picture_ids
- labels
- note
- timestamp

With this structure, querying data of a user's meals in a specified *day* may first filter `meals` by `user_id`, then by `timestamp`. And for one user, there will be multiple records inserted for multiple meals during one day.

Another way is use [json or jsonb type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html) to extract the "time" part from `timestamp` so the `timestamp` only contains 'year', 'month', 'date', thus I may have a table named `meals_of_day`:

**`meals_of_day`** (table name)

- id (primary key)
- user_id (foreign key)
- records (**json type**) <----------
- date

And data in the `records` column may look like:

```json
{
  "08:30": {
    picture_ids: [1,2],
    labels: ['meat', 'apple'],
    note: 'meat was too salty'
  },

  "12:45": {
    // some data
  },

  "19:05": {
    // some data
  }
}
```

This way, one user only has one row for each day, insertion of a meal is actually an updating of the `records` column of the row corresponding to `user`+`date`.

---

1. Which approach will have a shorter response time when a user log in a meal?
2. If the analytical feature involves a lot of time related queries, which approach would be more efficient?

Thanks.

Comment: I would consider the response time difference to be premature optimization. Even if one is 50% faster... you're probably talking sub-millisecond differences. There are many other considerations (like how these approaches impact your application layer, front-end, etc) I would consider, but not the difference in write performance.

Comment: What are the kind of time related queries that you want to do analytics on? You can index on keys inside of a JSONB, so it's possible to make queries against nested JSON data quite performant, but it depends greatly on what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of the two approaches (and knowing nothing about your application layer, front-end architecture, etc) I'd prefer the `meals` table approach. It's simple, fairly flexible (seems to make few assumptions about how the data will be used), prevents possible update-conflicts on the jSONB structure, and is fairly simple to migrate away from (to the mails_per_day approach or something else) should the need arise.

Comment: Thanks @melcher. Your comments and answer did mention me some concerns I haven't considered. The `meals_of_day` approach reduces some complexity on queries but it loses some flexibility. And using `json` or `jsonb` needs [more effort to implement constrains](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) upon that column. The frontend is still on prototyping phase, I build [a low fidelity prototype on figma](https://www.figma.com/proto/cpPIbnwWO6BBONS1IBYcbd/v1.0?node-id=122%3A389&scaling=scale-down&page-id=111%3A387&starting-point-node-id=235%3A437) if you were interested.

Comment: There is another table named `states` which takes inputs from users about their feelings at a certain moment.  `states` and `meals` will be shown on the same timeline to provide possible insights about the relationship between their diet habit and their states. And this `timeline + meals + states` graph can be viewed in different scales(day, week, month etc.).  The main data for each `meal` are photos a user takes, and my original thought was to implement a foreign key column of `array` type (see `picture_ids` in the question description) in the `meals` table to reference photos data.

Comment: Arrays of foreign keys are not supported (yet) in Postgres. See  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41054507/postgresql-array-of-elements-that-each-are-a-foreign-key

Comment: Instead you can have a meal_id foreign key on the pictures table or use a join table (e.g. “meals_pictures” with a picture_id and a meal_id)

Comment: I considered both join table and array of foreign keys. I thought I might use an array to hold all the ids of pictures for a meal, then use an inclusion check to find all corresponding pictures -- something like: `select * from pictures where id = ANY(picture_ids_of_a_meal);` [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643454/postgres-check-if-array-field-contains-value). But as the answer says this can't keep referential integrity, So I think **a join table is more viable.** Thanks @melcher : )