# Issues with the usage of @> operator in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm having a post, each post has tags (varchar[]), and I'm trying to find related ones according to tags. This is why I want to check if all tags of the target post or any of its subsets are contained in the 'tags' arrays of other posts.

I've checked several sources:

[Postgres: check if array field contains value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643454/postgres-check-if-array-field-contains-value)

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/functions-array.html

According to them, @> should be suitable for this case, however neither

```
select * from posts where tags @> '{"California", "K-8"}';
```

nor

```
select * from posts where tags @> array['California', 'K-8']::varchar[];
```

work properly: I got an empty result while I have two posts with tags:

```
{'California','K-8','Legislation','AB77'}, {'California','K-8','Tips & Tricks'}
```

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could advise a solution to this issue :-)

EDIT: I've figured out what was wrong - the issue was in the format of stored data: after I had changed

```
{'California','K-8','Tips & Tricks'}
```

to

```
{California,K-8,"Tips & Tricks"}
```

in pgAdmin everything started to work properly.

Comment: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/d6kKrov5orrPHf3KR1zi81/1 appears to works fine here. Could you post some of your data?

Comment: 'all tags of the target post or any of its subsets are contained in'. Isn't the empty array a subset of every array?  Or if you arbitrarily exclude that, then this sounds more like overlap `&&` than contains.

Comment: Don't edit the question to add the answer. Answer your own question. That is better to understand, and people may credit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've figured out what was wrong - the issue was in the format of stored data: after I had changed

`{'California','K-8','Tips & Tricks'}`
to

`{California,K-8,"Tips & Tricks"}`
in pgAdmin everything started to work properly.