# How to create query that checks if array contains value? golang gorm

Tags: arrays, database, postgresql, go, go-gorm

This is how model looks:

```
type Board struct {
    Id     uint `gorm:"primaryKey;autoIncrement;unique" json:"id"`
    Owner  uint `json:"owner"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Contributors datatypes.JSON `gorm:"type:jsonb" json:"contributors"`
    GeneratedLink string `gorm:"default:''" json:"generated_link"`
    Todos datatypes.JSON `gorm:"type:jsonb" json:"todos"`
}
```

This is how contributors value looks in the postgresql column:

[image]

and how to make query that checks that contributors array contains for example 20?
i tried to do like this: `database.DB.Where("contributors IN ?", 20).Find(&contBoards)`
but got error: `ERROR: syntax error at or near "$1" (SQLSTATE 42601)`

Please any ideas, any options.
P.S using gorm, postgresql

Comment: `IN` takes a slice as an argument.  Try something like `("contributors IN ?", []int{20})`

Comment: @sberry got an empty array but i should receive at least one column from table

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `IN` operator in the `WHERE` clause to check if a value matches any value in a list of values.

`IN` expects an explicit list of values (or a subquery).

I have created a sample scenario for your case as follows :

```
contributors := []int{20, 25, 27}

var tmp []string

for _, v := range contributors {
    tmp = append(tmp, fmt.Sprint(v))
}

query := "SELECT * from table_name where contributors in (" + strings.Join(tmp, ",") + ")"
```

OR

`ANY` works with arrays. This can be useful if you have the list of values already in an array.

With `ANY` operator you can search for only one value.

```
select * from table_name where value = ANY(contributors);
```

If you want to search multiple values, you can use `@>` operator.

`@>` is the "contains" operator.

Defined for several data types as follows :

arrays: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html

range types: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-range.html

geometric types: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html

JSON (and JSONB): http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html

For better understanding you can refer this link : [Postgres: check if array field contains value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643454/postgres-check-if-array-field-contains-value)

Comment: love you man! your sample is gold, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there are examples in gorm doc

db.Where("name IN ?", []string{"jinzhu", "jinzhu 2"}).Find(&users)