# Use Rails 'contains operator' (or alternative) for search with multiple values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I have two models: Author and Book, where

```
class Book< ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :author
end
class Author< ApplicationRecord
  has_many :books
 end
```

Author has a **name:string**

Book has **title:string** and **author_id as index**

I'm interested in finding all authors that have books that contain some given strings

eg if the terms are ['wizard', 'one hundred', 'two cities'] I want to return the authors whose books contain the terms in the title ( one book title containing 'wizard' AND one book containing 'one hundred' AND...)

I could go with something like

```
class Post
 scope :including_all_title, -> (titles) { where(matching_tag_query(titles, 'AND')) }

 private

  def matching_tag_query(titles, condition_separator = 'AND')
    titles.map { |t| "(title LIKE '%#{t}%')" }.join(" #{condition_separator} ")
 end
 end
```

**( Author.joins(:books).merge(Books.including_all_title... )**
but doesn't seem great as the number of terms increases.

I've seen responses that contain Postgres's  '@> ' ( eg   [Postgres: check if array field contains value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643454/postgres-check-if-array-field-contains-value/54069718#54069718))

but so far I couldn't make it work( probably syntax isn't good, I don't get an error but no results )

I'm wondering how could I achieve that with Active Record  ( or another solution better than my own)

**Edit**: I realise I might have been unclear, what I'm trying to do is:
If `Author(name:'John')` has books `Book(title: 'The wonderful Wizard of Oz')`
`Book(title: 'Fantastic beasts')`
`Book(title: 'Some other work')`
`Book(title: 'Another book')`  and I query by `["%wizard%", "%fantastic%"]` I would want to find the author whose books , match **ALL** of the keywords, so in this case John would be a match( because "wizard" matches one book, and "fantastic" matches another,  even if some are unmatched- I'm interested in my keywords)

Comment: If `books.title` isn't json then you can not use `@>`. Otherwise it should work as it says in that answer.

Comment: On the answer I've posted, the field on which @>  is used seems to be of character varying ( varchar(200) .

Comment: It seems so, but there's no operator @> for strings in Postgres (that I'm aware). Check the docs for strings and json (https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-string.html, https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-json.html)

Comment: Thank you, 
I've seen that with Postgres, a flag like `array: true` can be added  on the string column ( title in my case) . Would that be of any help?

Comment: That's for declaring your column is of array type. It'd make your title column store an array of strings, but that's not what you probably want here.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
def matching_tag_query(titles, condition_separator = 'AND')
  titles.map { |t| "(title LIKE '%#{t}%')" }.join(" #{condition_separator} ")
end
```

but it is subject to SQL injection and you can make it cleaner using PostgreSQL's [`expr op any(array)` and `expr op all(array)`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-comparisons.html) with the ILIKE operator. Something more like this:

```
scope :including_all_title, -> (titles) { where('title ilike all(array[?])', titles.map { |t| "%#{sanitize_sql_like(t)}%" })
scope :including_any_title, -> (titles) { where('title ilike any(array[?])', titles.map { |t| "%#{sanitize_sql_like(t)}%" })
```

Should be fine for realistic `titles` but if someone throws a couple thousand `titles` at you then it could run into query size limits and it wouldn't find anything anyway.

---

In response to the comments: If you want to find all the books that match any of the keywords then:

```
books = Book.where('title like any(array[?])', titles.map { |t| "%#{sanitize_sql_likt(t)}%" })
```

Then to find the authors:

```
Author.where(id: books.select(:author_id))
```

That'll do a subquery like this:

```
select *
from authors
where id in (select author_id from books where ...)
```

which won't be as efficient as it could be but should be good enough. If it is too slow, convert it to a JOIN.

Comment: Thank you for the response, 
I've tried in the console like :
`Author.joins(:books).merge(Book.where("title ilike all(array[?])", ["%wizard", "%fantastic%"]))` 
and even if one of my authors has titles that contain that, it fails to bring him up ( the author also has other entries besides those ) - for one string, it brings results

Comment: (1) Use `all` if you want to match all of them, `any` if you want to match at least one. (2) You'd want `["%wizard%", "%fantastic%"]` rather than `["%wizard", "%fantastic%"]` (note the percents around "wizard").

Comment: Sorry, my example was wrong: I've used the wildcard operator, like mentioned, as in 
`Author.joins(:books).merge(Book.where("title ilike all(array[?])", ["%wizard%", "%fantastic%"])) `
but still didn't get the expected result

Comment: What is the expected result? Which title are you expecting to find?

Comment: I am expecting Author as result eg if Author(name:'John') has books 
Book(title: 'The wonderful Wizard of Oz')
 Book(title: 'Fantastic beasts')  
Book(title: 'Some other work') 
and I query by ["%wizard%", "%fantastic%"]  I would want to get the Author with name John as result ( or more authors if they also match the condition)

Comment: Have a look at my update.

Comment: Thank you for the post- currently it still doesn't bring the desired outcome(it brings authors that have just one of them) and I'm sorry I was unclear (I've updated the question on top ) 
 I would want to find the author whose books  match **ALL** of the keywords, so in this case John would be a match( because "wizard" matches one book, and "fantastic" matches another, even if some are unmatched- I'm interested in my keywords)