# SQL statement with 'ANY' to Linq

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

How to convert the following SQL statement to Linq statement?

`select * from "schema_test".project where 'User1'=ANY("collaborators");`

Here collaborators is a character varying array.

Note: The contains operator throws error at the postgre side as it is meant only for Array to array  comparison.
Sample Linq which has error - `context.Projects.Where(x => x.Collaborators.Contains(userId))`

Any suggestions would help a lot.

Comment: Check [documentation](https://www.npgsql.org/efcore/mapping/array.html) what is supported

Comment: @Dai  No, it is not false always. You can refer this answer - [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643454/postgres-check-if-array-field-contains-value)  Please suggest if there are other ways to do this

Comment: @RakshithaVasishta Sorry, I didn't see the double-quotes there, I thought you were comparing two literal strings.

Comment: *which has error* - what error?