# How to get intersection of two arrays/lists in sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have similar problem to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39643454/postgres-check-if-array-field-contains-value) (most similar is the answer with `&&`). For postgres, I would like to get the intersection of array column and python list. I've tried to do that with `&&` operator:

```py
query(Table.array_column.op('&&')(cast(['a', 'b'], ARRAY(Unicode)))).filter(Table.array_column.op('&&')(cast(['a', 'b'], ARRAY(Unicode))))
```

but it seems that `op('&&')` return `bool` type (what has sense for filter) not the intersection.

So for table data:

```
id   |   array_column
1        {'7', 'xyz', 'a'}
2        {'b', 'c', 'd'}
3        {'x', 'y', 'ab'}
4        {'ab', 'ba', ''}
5        {'a', 'b', 'ab'}
```

I would like to get:

```
id   |   array_column
1        {'a'}
2        {'b'}
5        {'a', 'b'}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way<sup>*</sup> to do this would be to unnest the array column, and then re-aggregate the rows that match the list values, grouping on id. This could be done as a subquery:

```sql
select id, array_agg(un) 
  from (select id, unnest(array_column) as un from tbl) t
  where un in ('a', 'b') 
  group by id 
  order by id;
```

The equivalent SQLAlchemy construct is:

```py
subq = sa.select(
    tbl.c.id, sa.func.unnest(tbl.c.array_column).label('col')
).subquery('s')
stmt = (
    sa.select(subq.c.id, sa.func.array_agg(subq.c.col))
    .where(subq.c.col.in_(['a', 'b']))
    .group_by(subq.c.id)
    .order_by(subq.c.id)
)
```

returning

```
(1, ['a'])
(2, ['b'])
(5, ['a', 'b'])
```

---

<sup>*</sup> There may well be more efficient ways.