# filter data on the basis of array elements in strapi

Tags: javascript, postgresql, filtering, content-management-system, strapi

Here is what my Post data object looks like:

```
{
      "id": 23,
      "attributes": {
        "title": " Ea omnis voluptatem quo error quos qui quia",
        "content": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Ut enim sunt 33 molestiae ullam ad maxime placeat et quia iusto. Aut rerum eius est voluptatem sint ut dolorum accusamus At perspiciatis incidunt in delectus eligendi et iste dolore ea tenetur necessitatibus?",
        "createdAt": "2023-10-17T04:46:50.824Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-10-17T04:52:35.871Z",
        "publishedAt": "2023-10-17T04:50:43.222Z",
        "categories": [
          "featured",
          "investing"
        ],
        "seoTags": [
          "investing"
        ],
        "newsDate": "2023-10-17T04:30:38.237Z",
        "timeToRead": 10,
        "author": "Author"
      }
    },
```

I want to get all the posts that have "featured" in the categories array. I am using this query:

```
http://localhost:1337/api/generated-posts?filters[categories][$contains]=featured
```

I tried a similar thing before on another collection when i was using sqllite, it worked then but now that I am on postgres it shows me this error:

```
error: select "t0".* from "public"."generated_posts" as "t0" where ("t0"."categories" like $1 and "t0"."published_at" is not null) limit $2 - operator does not exist: jsonb ~~ unknown
```

i have also tried the $in operator but that also doesn't work:
`http://localhost:1337/api/generated-posts?filters[categories][$in]=featured`
please somebody help me to filter this data

Comment: What is your `generated_posts` table's structure?

Comment: id integer
title character varying
content text
created_at timestamp without time zone
updated_at timestamp without time zone
published_at timestamp without time zone
created_by_id integer
updated_by_id integer
categories jsonb
seo_tags jsonb
news_date timestamp without time zone
time_to_read integer
author character varying

Comment: Then here is your query `select  * from generated_posts where categories @> to_jsonb($1::text) and published_at is not null`. It uses the `@>` ['contains'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36985926/what-does-the-operator-in-postgres-do) JSONB operator.

Comment: I didn't understand what will be the query in this format "http://localhost:1337/api/generated-posts?filters[categories][$in]=featured". like what is the mistake in this query and how to get the data